# Как написать скрипт на питоне, который выгружает нужные данные с wikidata

Tags: python, python-3.x, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Я хочу научиться работать с данными из Wikidata. Мне нужно написать скрипт на питоне, которые получает в качестве параметров наименование населенного пункта, его тип и характеристику, которую необходимо узнать и необязательный параметр год, а возвращается значение данной характеристики.
Например: geo_fact(China, country, population, 2013) должен вернуть 1 357 000 000.

Если точного ответа по году нет, то ищется ближайший год.

Характеристики, которые должны быть поддержаны: capital, population, area, currency.

Совсем не понимаю, как это можно реализовать. Я почитала про pywikibot, но это не очень помогло мне понять, что нужно сделать, чтобы написать нужный скрипт. Помогите, пожалуйста. Хотя бы ссылку, где можно посмотреть и откуда можно почерпать информацию, чтобы написать работающий скрипт

Вот уже что-то написала , этот код пока только ищет в поиске в API Wikidata , местность name

```
import requests
import re
import codecs
def  geo_fact():
    res = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=' + 'Russian' + '&language=en&format=json')
    regular = re.compile(r'Q\d+')
    matches = re.findall(regular, res.text)
    for item in matches:
        temp_res = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/' + item)
        r = re.compile(answer, temp_res.text)
```

Comment: можете показать где вы нашли данные о населении Китая за 2013 год __в Wikipedia__?

Comment: Я ввела в поиске гугла "население Китая 2013", но там выдалась статистика из сайта всемирного банка (https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?end=2017&start=2013). То есть информация не из Wikidata. Но в Wikidata вроде бы есть все, может поэтому эту информацию оттуда лучше брать? Я вот сама толком не знаю, но мне бы очень хотелось понять, как такие данные находить в свободном доступе и выгружать их с помощью питона

Comment: Если очень нужно помочь с реализацией, чуть позже подгоню скрипт.. а пока только вот ещё один вариант нашел: https://pypi.org/project/Wikidata/

Comment: Буду очень благодарна, если есть возможность помочь с реализацией)) Я посмотрела ссылку, но вот там они уже заранее знают, что ищут информацию в Q20145 (это какая-то корейская певица и актриса), а я при получении параметров, переданных в функцию, знаю лишь название местности (а объект в викидате, который характеризует эту местность, -  не знаю). То есть, например, Я ввожу geo_fact(Russia, country, population, 2016) , и я не совсем понимаю, откуда сама функция должна узнать, что ей нужно рассматривать объект Q159.

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk, я думала использовать библиотеку requests , но все равно особо не понимаю, как организовать концепцию функции

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример получения данных.. все что получилось сделать - это найти указанный запрос, определить его id, получить описание и получить какие-то данные.. в структуре самых данных пока не разобрался

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pywikibot
from wikidata.client import Client


def geo_fact(obj):
    site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
    page = pywikibot.Page(site, obj['name'])
    item = pywikibot.ItemPage.fromPage(page)

    client = Client()
    entity = client.get(item.id, load=True)
    print(entity.description)
    print(entity.data)


obj = {'name': "China", 'type': "country"}
geo_fact(obj)
```

и ещё в директории со скриптом нужно создать файл user-config.py с содержимим:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

family = 'wikidata'
mylang = 'ru'
```

мне на самом деле довольно интересна эта тема, если хотите, напишите мне на почту olekmay@gmail.com